# How does SonarQube users table work?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

Can someone explain to me how users are stored SonarQube's database (mysql)? I did a wrong query that corrupted a new user's account. I am trying to fix it but I can't get the user to show up again on the /users page so something must still not be quite right even though everything look correct in the "users" table. Is there any other table involved?

The user is new so he has not activity in the DB (never logged in, nothing assigned etc.).

Alternatively I am ok deleting the user and recreating, but I don't know how to do that since it doesn't show in the web ui. To do it in the DB I would need again to know the data model.

Comment: What kind of "wrong query" did you do to corrupt datastore ? SQL or web service ?

Comment: SQL. I tried to change the "login" of the new user because I had made a typo. Since the user was not yet used at that point, I thought there was little chance that the login was referenced anywhere else in the db (assuming the id was the real key). I was wrong since the user then disappeared from the users page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should revert your SQL change, delete the directory data/es then delete the user through the standard way (administration console or web service). If you don't know what was the exact change, then a database backup should be restored.

Comment: I had tried to revert my changes without success. Thanks to your answer I figured out why: I needed to delete the data/es folder which I assume is caching some data. Thank you so much for helping me fix the mess that I had created and for your great product!

Answer (score 0):

In order for a user to appear on the UI, you need to make sure they are linked to an organization via the `organization_members` table.  On my setup, I only have one organization (in the `organizations` table), the default one.